# Angular UI typeahead startswith

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I have a problem with typeahead. I have a field with name and surname of a person, If I type A I would like to see the focus on the surname and not on the leading character that is the name.

this is an example:

```
 function TypeaheadCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.selected = undefined;
        $scope.Person = ['Jane Smith', 'John Smith', 'Sam Smith', 'John Doe','Daniel Doe'];
    }
```

When I type S i Would like to see only jane smith and john smith. There's a way to do this??

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/inwmqYCCRsjs1G91Sa3Q?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you would want each of the listed items found in the ***sourceArray*** to have the search term highlighted only for the surname. That is not possible without modifying the directive itself, but I have an alternate solution that, although it also highlights the search term in the first name (if matched), ***ONLY*** presents results for persons with a surname matched by the search term. I hope this helps:

```js
angular.module("firstChar", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

angular.module("firstChar").controller("TypeaheadCtrl", function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.selected = undefined;
  
  // ==========================================================
  // You would have to replace the JSON assignment code below
  // with a call to $http.get, to get that file you talked
  // about in your comment below:
  //
  // $http.get('OutAnagrafica.json').success(function (data) {
  //    $scope.OutAnagrafica = data;
  // });
  //
  // ==========================================================
  
  $scope.OutAnagrafica = [
    {
        "Name": "Jane Smith"
    },
    {
        "Name": "John Smith"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sam Smith"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sam Northrop"
    },
    {
        "Name": "John Doe"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Daniel Doe"
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.persons = $scope.OutAnagrafica.map(function (person) {
    var nameParts = person.Name.split(" "),
        name = nameParts[0],
        surname = nameParts.slice(1).join(" ");
    
    return {
      "name": name,
      "surname": surname
    };
  });
  
  $scope.getPersonsFromSurnames = function(searchTerm) {
    return $filter("filter")($scope.persons.map(function (person) {
      return {
        "fullname": person.name + " " + person.surname,
        "surname": person.surname
      };
    }), {
      "surname": searchTerm
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="firstChar">
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <div>Selected: <span>{{selected}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="person.fullname for person in getPersonsFromSurnames($viewValue)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is what I want! But If I have a json file like this: [
            {
              " Name": "jane Smith"
               
            },
            {
                "Name": "John Smith"
            },
               
            {
            "Name": "Sam Smith"
              
                }       
            ]   How can I split it?

Comment: I read this in my project with a http call: $http.get('OutAnagrafica.json')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.OutAnagrafica = data;

        });

Comment: Do you mean you need to re-process your JSON to separate name from surname?, because what the getPersonsFromSurnames is doing is basically filtering after extracting surnames from the names. If what you want is pre-processing it and then simplify the search, we can go that way too. Let me know.

Comment: If what you need is just process the JSON data you get from that $http.get call and split it in "name" and "surname" fields, then you only need to do something like:`$scope.persons = $scope.OutAnagrafica.map(function (person) {
    var nameParts = person.split(" "),
     name = nameParts[0],
  surname = nameParts.slice(1).join(" ");
    
    return {
     "name": name,
  "surname": surname
    };
});`

Comment: mmm yes, I thought that i could split the field so I can filter based on the surname like the first example you've made. What is the best solution?

Comment: The ideal solution is to get the original JSON file with the name and surname fields. If that is not possible, the second best is using the ***map*** function in my previous comment, and change the filtering code for it. If you would like me to change my answer to use a JSON-based variable instead (seemingly, I cannot include an "inline" file in the code snippet), I can do that, modifying the example. If with these comments plus my above answer are enough, then please mark my answer as correct. Let me know.

Comment: If you could change the example using the map function with json would be great! Of course I will mark your answer.

Comment: I edited my answer with your newly-requested changes. I hope this answer will help you with your project.

Comment: I see that you have not marked my answer as correct. Did this work for you or not? Please, let me know.

Comment: Yes sorry I hadn't time to answer but I don't understand why in my project doesn't work

Comment: Let me know your needs. We may continue evaluating your problem. I am committed to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new in web programming! Maybe can I try to re-process the json? I have a list and when I try the previuos solution the list is not printed.

Comment: I really think there is nothing wrong with pre-processing JSON, as long as you keep updates synchronized with the newly-processed model. You can use the same ***map*** function to produce the new model for your JSON. Maybe we should connect in Google+ so we can do this using a hangout.

Comment: Can I have your email so I can write you in private?

Comment: Contact me on Google+. The link is in my profile. Just ask to be added and tell me you are "sidos". I will add you and we can go on from there.

Answer (score 0):

From http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead,
looking at this particular line

`<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http"       typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">`

You can probably do something like

`<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="name for name in getPersonLastName($viewValue)">`

Meaning that you have a getPersonLastName function that looks into $scope.Person and returns names that matches the surname with the $viewValue.